# How to vectorize indexing and computation when indexed tensors are different dimensions?

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize the following for-loop in Pytorch. I'd be happy with just vectorizing the inner for-loop, but doing the whole batch would also be awesome.

```
# B: the batch size
# N: the number of training examples 
# dim: the dimension of each feature vector
# K: the number of discrete labels. each vector has a single label
# delta: margin for hinge loss

batch_data = torch.tensor(...)  # Tensor of shape [B x N x d]
batch_labels = torch.tensor(...)  # Tensor of shape [B x N x 1], each element is one of K labels (ints)

batch_losses = []  # Ultimately should be [B x 1]
batch_centroids = []  # Ultimately should be [B x K_i x dim]
for i in range(B):
    centroids = []  # Keep track of the means for each class. 
    classes = torch.unique(labels)  # Get the unique labels for the classes.

    # NOTE: The number of classes K for each item in the batch might actually
    # be different. This may complicate batch-level operations.

    total_loss = 0

    # For each class independently. This is the part I want to vectorize.
    for cl in classes:
        # Take the subset of training examples with that label.
        subset = data[torch.where(labels == cl)]

        # Find the centroid of that subset.
        centroid = subset.mean(dim=0)
        centroids.append(centroid)
  
        # Get the distance between each point in the subset and the centroid.
        dists = subset - centroid
        norm = torch.linalg.norm(dists, dim=1)

        # The loss is the mean of the hinge loss across the subset.
        margin = norm - delta
        hinge = torch.clamp(margin, min=0.0) ** 2

        total_loss += hinge.mean()

    # Keep track of everything. If it's too hard to keep track of centroids, that's also OK.
    loss = total_loss.mean()
    batch_losses.append(loss)
    batch_centroids.append(centroids)
```

I've been scratching my head on how to deal with the irregularly sized tensors. The number of classes in each batch `K_i` is different, and the size of each subset is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out it actually *is* possible to vectorize across ragged arrays. I'll use numpy, but code should be directly translatable to torch. The key technique is to:

1. Sort by ragged array membership
2. Perform an accumulation
3. Find boundary indices, compute adjacent differences

For a single (non-batch) input of an `n x d` matrix `X` and an `n`-length array `label`, the following returns the `k x d` centroids and `n`-length distances to respective centroids:

```
def vcentroids(X, label):
    """
    Vectorized version of centroids.
    """        
    # order points by cluster label
    ix = np.argsort(label)
    label = label[ix]
    Xz = X[ix]
    
    # compute pos where pos[i]:pos[i+1] is span of cluster i
    d = np.diff(label, prepend=0) # binary mask where labels change
    pos = np.flatnonzero(d) # indices where labels change
    pos = np.repeat(pos, d[pos]) # repeat for 0-length clusters
    pos = np.append(np.insert(pos, 0, 0), len(X))
    
    Xz = np.concatenate((np.zeros_like(Xz[0:1]), Xz), axis=0)
    Xsums = np.cumsum(Xz, axis=0)
    Xsums = np.diff(Xsums[pos], axis=0)
    counts = np.diff(pos)
    c = Xsums / np.maximum(counts, 1)[:, np.newaxis]
    
    repeated_centroids = np.repeat(c, counts, axis=0)
    aligned_centroids = repeated_centroids[inverse_permutation(ix)]
    dist = np.sum((X - aligned_centroids) ** 2, axis=1)
    
    return c, dist
```

Batching requires little special handling. For an input `B x n x d` array `batch_X`, with `B x n` batch labels `batch_labels`, create unique labels for each batch:

```
batch_k = batch_labels.max(axis=1) + 1
batch_k[1:] = batch_k[:-1]
batch_k[0] = 0
base = np.cumsum(batch_k)
batch_labels += base.expand_dims(1)
```

So now each batch element has a unique contiguous range of labels. I.e., the first batch element will have `n` labels in some range `[0, k0)` where `k0 = batch_k[0]`, the second will have range `[k0, k0 + k1)` where `k1 = batch_k[1]`, etc.

Then just flatten the `n x B x d` input to `n*B x d` and call the same vectorized method. Your loss function is derivable using the final distances and same position-array based reduction technique.

For a detailed explanation of how the vectorization works, see [my blog post](https://vladfeinberg.com/2021/01/07/vectorizing-ragged-arrays.html?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=torch_centroids).

Comment: Thanks - there were some complexities when transferring this to torch, but certainly provided a substantial speedup in evaluation vs. the non-vectorized code. I haven't properly benchmarked things, but it sped up my training pipeline by ~20% per batch, which I'm happy about. Unclear how much improvement came from forward vs backward pass in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize the whole thing if you use a one-hot encoding for your classes and a [pairwise distance trick](https://jbencook.com/pairwise-distance-in-numpy/) for your norms:

```
import torch

B = 32
N = 1000
dim = 50
K = 25

batch_data = torch.randn((B, N, dim))
batch_labels = torch.randint(0, K, size=(B, N))
batch_one_hot = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(batch_labels)

centroids = torch.matmul(
    batch_one_hot.transpose(-1, 1).type(batch_data.dtype),
    batch_data
) / batch_one_hot.sum(1)[..., None]

norms = torch.linalg.norm(batch_data[:, :, None] - centroids[:, None], axis=-1)

# Compute the rest of your loss
# ...
```

A couple things to watch out for:

1. You'll get a divide by zero for any batches that have a missing class. You can handle this by first computing the class sums (with matmul) and counts (summing the one-hot tensor along axis 1) separately. Then, mask the sums with count == 0 and divide the rest of them by their class counts.
2. If you have a large number of classes, this will cause memory problems because the one-hot tensor will be too big. In that case, the answer from @VF1 probably makes more sense.